flutter - url_launcher wont work when app downloeded from store
Here's my code using url_launcher:
dart
Copy code
void _handleLinkTap() async {
    String? url = widget.snap["pageUrlMap"][widget.snap["uuids"][_selectedImageIndex]];
    if (url != null) {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
      try {
        await launchUrl(uri);
      } catch (e) {
        // Error handling: open in web browser if the app cannot handle the URL
        if (url.startsWith('http://') || url.startsWith('https://')) {
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
        } else {
          await launchUrl(Uri.parse('http://$url'));
        }
      }
    }
  }

This code works fine in both debug and release modes on my device. However, after publishing my app update to the store, I realized that the links won't open when the app is downloaded from the store (on both iOS and Android).
Here's my previous code, which worked fine even in the downloaded version of the app:
dart
Copy code
// Deprecated
/*void _handleLinkTap() async {
    String? url = widget.snap["pageUrlMap"][widget.snap["uuids"][_selectedImageIndex]];
    if (url != null) {
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
      try {
        await launchUrl(uri);
      } catch (e) {
     // Error handling: open in web browser if the app cannot handle the URL
        if (url.startsWith('http://') || url.startsWith('https://')) {
          await launch(url);
        } else {
          await launch('http://$url');
        }
      }
    }
  }*/

In my case:
The updated function works well in release and debug modes but does not work when the app is downloaded from the store (both iOS and Android).
Because there are no errors in debug and release modes, I can't test the issue directly. I can only upload a new version to the store, hoping it will work.
If anyone knows a solution, please share it. Otherwise, I might have to revert to using the deprecated function again.
expect to open links even in launched mode of app

Have you tried using different launch modes?
I usually use platformDefault for iOS and externalApplication for Android.
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  launchUrl(
    Uri.parse('https://yourfancywebsite.com'),
    mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault,
  );
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  launchUrl(
    Uri.parse('https://yourfancywebsite.com'),
    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
  );
}

Here are all the possible
LaunchModes
